# control of existence or not of paragraph in exsheet header in question and solution environments

Tags: environments, paragraphs, exsheets

I'm new to `exsheets` (started to use it today), just installed the latest version. After some experiments I think I got the basics to start using it, regularly, except for one esthetics thing I would like to fix: 
How to avoid the paragraph after the "Exercise" or "Solution" in order the body of  question or answer starts in the same line of the header.

I found here in tex.stackexchange a solution you provided for a related problem, using the commands `\exsheets_par:` and `\scan_stop:`
I tried that just after `\begin{document}` and also inside
`\SetupExSheets{...}`. May be these are  wrong places to use it in the LaTeX file, or the way to use is not  `\exsheets_par:`= `\scan_stop:` as I did.

Searched for some reference to this possible option in the document, but found nothing.

Any advice to solve my problem is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. 1) I don't quite understand what your trying to do but if you're actually using `\exsheets_par:` when trying to change the layout you're probably doing something wrong. `exsheets` supports quite a variety of layouts. 2) Since a few weeks `exsheets` has been superseded by http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsim If you are new to `exsheets` then I suggest you switch to the new package.

Comment: 3) Re: “*just installed the latest version.*” that wouldn't have been necessary if you have an up to date TeX distribution where the latest version already is included. Both `exsheets` and `xsim` depend on certain versions of other packages so a manual installation might lead to other problems if the TeX distribution isn't up to date.

Comment: 4) Re “*How to avoid the paragraph after the "Exercise" or "Solution" in order the body of question or answer starts in the same line of the header.*” You probably just want `\SetupExSheets{headings=runin}`

Comment: Dear  Clemens, thank you for your prompt answer to my question. I just wanted that  the body of the question/ solution started in the same line as the header "Exercices 7" or, "solution 7", etc.   

Your  \SetupExSheets{headings=runin} solved the problem. I haven't seen that in previous posts (as of 2014,  of course a lot of things happened since then): Thank you also for pointing me for the new package xsim. I just installed it (my miktex wizard was not updated since February), and late night I will try to switch to it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you simply want the option `headings=runin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings = runin
}

% dummy text:
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: since a few weeks `exsheets` has been superseded by its successor `xsim`.  The same with this package needs more effort, though, as it comes with very little predefined layouts.  The following provides a very similar layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\usepackage{needspace}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{runin}
  {%
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \textbf{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} % <<< notice the space
    \IfInsideSolutionF{%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{%
        \marginpar{%
          \printgoal{\PropertyValue}%
          \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{+\printgoal{\PropertyValue}}%
          \,\IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
          {\XSIMtranslate{point}}
          {\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
  {}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template=runin ,
  solution/template=runin ,
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}.
}

% dummy text:
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you save the `\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{runin}{...}{...}` together with `\RequirePackage{needspace}` in a file called `xsim.mylayouts.code.tex` somewhere where TeX can find, eg your project folder,

```
\xsimstyle*{mylayouts}

\RequirePackage{needspace}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{runin}
  {%
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \textbf{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} % <<< notice the space
    \IfInsideSolutionF{%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{%
        \marginpar{%
          \printgoal{\PropertyValue}%
          \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{+\printgoal{\PropertyValue}}%
          \,\IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
          {\XSIMtranslate{point}}
          {\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
  {}

\endinput
```

the preamble can be shortened to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\loadxsimstyle{mylayouts}% <<< this

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template=runin ,
  solution/template=runin ,
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}.
}

% dummy text:
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: In fact I wanted something more, namely to link back and forth from solution to exercise. I just copy pasted from your older post and what  I have now is 
\SetupExSheets{
headings=runin,
  question/pre-body-hook = {%
    \hyperlink{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{Solution
      \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}\par
  },
  solution/pre-hook = {
    \hypertarget{sol:\CurrentQuestionID}{}%
  } ,
  solution/pre-body-hook = {% \hyperref[qu:\CurrentQuestionID]{Exercice
      \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}}\par
  } 
}
Works fine. Thanks for your great  work.

Comment: And thanks for your instructions on how to start with xsim  . I'll do that.

Comment: `xsim` comes with a whole lot of examples: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/examples

Comment: @clemens The link in your comment is in 404, it should be replaced by http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/doc/examples/

Comment: @Clément or a bit more generic http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/doc/examples Thanks

Comment: You wrote "in a file called xsim.mylayouts.code.tex somewhere where TeX can find, eg your project folder". `loadxsimstyle` doesn't support relative addressing, right? That is, I can't store  xsim.mylayouts.code.tex in a subfolder of my project, correct? (Unless I change my `'$TEXMFHOME'` or something alike, I assume)

Comment: @Clément personally I would install it in the local texmf tree. Then you would have it available for every project...